# How to parse csv containing JSON type column

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python to parse a CSV which contains JSON type:

| cast | id |
| --- | --- |
| {"user":"a","character":"AA"},{"user":"b","character":"BB"} | 1 |
| {"user":"c","character":"CC"} | 2 |

How can I make this CSV be:

| cast | id |
| --- | --- |
| ["AA","BB"] | 1 |
| ["CC"] | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import json


df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')
df.cast = df.cast.apply(lambda r: [x.get('character') for x in json.loads('[' + r + ']')])
```

The [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) method is used to apply a function on a column.
You can use the json module to parse the JSON string. [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) returns a dictionary, I had to add the brackets to make the string a valid JSON string (list of mappings).

Comment: Could you tell me what does `json.loads('['+r+']')` mean? why do not put `df['cast']` inside?

Answer (score 1):

use `regexp` to extract the `character` content,
if you only want to use that field.

```
df['cast_list'] = df['cast'].str.findall('"character":"(.*?)"')
```